# Kafka multiple Logstash integration issue

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, apache-zookeeper

I have a 6 node cluster running kafka broker on 3 machines and a topic with 18 partitions.
I started logstash process on 3 out of six nodes with a common consumer group subscribing to this topic.

But when I describe consumer-group:

```
/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server : --group --describe
```

It shows a same logstash owner for all 18 partitions. Shouldn't I see the partitions divided among 3 logstash processes that I have running on 2 nodes. Rightnow looks like only one logstash consumer is working.

Plus from 
    zkCli.sh ls /consumers doesn't show

Restarting ZK and kafka doesn't help.

Here is my logstash input section:

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "ip-...internal:6667,ip-.internal:6667"
    group_id => "my-group"
    topics => ["input"]
    consumer_threads => 2
  }
}
```

Comment: did you solve it?